# How to fix 'Command errored out with exit status 1' with pip install

Tags: python, pip, centos7, pytype

I'm experiencing some trouble installing pytype with `pip install` as shown here:

OS: CentOS 7

Python: Python 3.6

Pip: 20.0.2

```
$ pip3 install pytype
Collecting pytype
  Using cached pytype-2020.2.20.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/aeu1/venv/bin/python3 /home/aeu1/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp34nr30o0
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z9y24cb4/pytype
  Complete output (7 lines):
  running egg_info
  writing pytype.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to pytype.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing entry points to pytype.egg-info/entry_points.txt
  writing requirements to pytype.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to pytype.egg-info/top_level.txt
  error: package directory 'find:' does not exist
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/aeu1/venv/bin/python3 /home/aeu1/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmp34nr30o0 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: _Check the logs for full command output._ Did you?

Comment: `pip install -U pybind11` did the trick for me

Answer (score 17):

That package directory `find:` comes from `setup.cfg`; it's actually not a package directory  but an instruction for `setuptools` to find a list of subdirectories to install.

I successfully installed the package for Python 2.7 and 3.5. So my advice is to upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

and then retry `pip install pytype`.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my issue when trying to install "selenium" on a mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

pip install -U pip setuptools

It worked for python 2.7.You need upgrade pip and setuptools

Answer (score -1):

When I updated Python to version 3.9 then I was unable to install [Pandas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandas_%28software%29) and [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) in [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm) which was giving me an error, 'Command errored out with exit status 1'.

The solution is to install an old version of Python 3.8.5 and use that as the interpreter.

Comment: Read the question! It says using python 3.6

Comment: Thanks @samb003, I also came to this page via Google, looking for the solution to the same error but in PyCharm on Mac OS Big Sur (though it is not the original question). Your suggestion to downgrade Python from 3.9 to 3.8 resolved the issue. Leaving this note here in case others run into same/similar issue.